QT + Rviz run bug
When I try to use QT+Rviz to create my ROS GUI APP. and everything was OK. But when I use Rviz Display to sub Path(nav_msgs::Path), well, a BUG happened.
[ WARN] [1734599789.335475585]: OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Cannot create GL vertex buffer in GLHardwareVertexBuffer::GLHardwareVertexBuffer at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/RenderSystems/GL/src/OgreGLHardwareVertexBuffer.cpp (line 47)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Ogre::InternalErrorException'
  what():  OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Cannot create GL vertex buffer in GLHardwareVertexBuffer::GLHardwareVertexBuffer at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/RenderSystems/GL/src/OgreGLHardwareVertexBuffer.cpp (line 47)
Aborted

My OS is Ubuntu16.04
My ROS version Kinetic
The bug happened when I check the box as follows：

Or in my code
path_->setEnabled(true)

